# How to save recent searches with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms

When user perform a search, these search settings should be saved for future use.

User should fill some form fields and then perform a search. When he perform a new search, the old one should be able, etc, etc.

Im using javascript, jQuery.

How could I do this?

I mean save it in localmachine, not in database.

Comment: Have you tried looking into the localstorage API? The best thing to do is attempt to do something and when you get stuck post the code and where you're stuck and people tend to be happy to help, but it's hard when there's no code yet :)

Comment: But i just dont know how to start :s im a begginer, Im looking here for a litle help, just to get started

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use HTML5 Local Storage to store and read saved searches.:

```
// Write a local item..
localStorage.setItem("myKey", "myValue");

// Read a local item..
var theItemValue = localStorage.getItem("myKey");

// Check for changes in the local item and log them..
window.addEventListener('storage', function(event) {
    console.log('The value for ' + event.key + ' was changed from' + event.oldValue + ' to ' + event.newValue);
}, false);

// Check for HTML5 Storage..
function supports_html5_storage() {
    try {
        return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try this plugin https://sites.google.com/site/daveschindler/jquery-html5-storage-plugin

your goal is to just save the searches, once they enter them before you do the action, so onSubmit of the form, save it to local storage using the plug in, and then perform the search.

You also need to load from storage each time the user visits the page, to grab the last few searches.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cookies or Web Storage. Cookies are supported by more browsers, but Web Storage is easier to use. If you use cookies, I recommend this jQuery plugin https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

To save a setting `$.cookie('key', 'value');`

To read a setting `$.cookie('key');`

Using Web Storage supported by latest versions of all major browsers:

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value);
localStorage.getItem(key, value);
```

You can use Google to find more details about the API

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR I've written a library to handle this + it's edge cases, see https://github.com/JonasBa/recent-searches#readme for usage.**

While all examples are technically ok, they do not cover any edge cases of storing recent searches such as implementing expiration, ranking or limits for LocalStorage space.

**Examples**
Expiration:
Consider that someone searches for a query `iPhone`, but has looked for a query `repairing iPhone` 1 month ago, that repairing iPhone query is likely obsolete.

**Ranking of recent searches**
Same goes for ranking when doing prefix search, if a user has made a query "apple television" 3h ago and a query "television cables" 8h ago, and they now search for "television", you want to probably implement a ranking system for the two.

*Safely handling storage*
Just writing to LocalStorage will result in a massive JSON that you'll need to parse every time, thus gradually slowing down your application until you hit the limit and loose this functionality.

Exactly because of that problem, I've built a recent-searches library which helps you tackle all that. You can use it via npm and find it [here](https://github.com/JonasBa/recent-searches#readme). It will help you with all of the above issues and allow you to build recent-searches really quickly!